# Implementing a SAML SSO in Java

Tags: java, authentication, saml

I have an application (AppA) that needs to access a URL over another application (AppB).

AppB is the service provider and also has the identity provider.

I want to create an automatic way of my application accessing the URL's at AppA.

I know that in the SAML protocol after the service provider gives the user(in this case my app) the authentication url the user is required to sign in with a user an a password. I wanted to know if there's a generic way of implementing this sign or I must implement something like a POST request with a user and password that I already have?

Comment: Rephrasing to make sure I understand: AppA needs to access resources provided by AppB which is protected by some sort of web access control system?

Answer (score 0):

In the SAML world you have an identity decision point (idp), a policy decision point (pdp) and policy enforcement point (pep) and a service, you want to call. The idp provides authentication in a way that a user can proof his identity. The pdp trust the idp and will decide which level of authorization a user wil get providing a valid idp document. The pep will allow or deny access to the service based on the pdp document.

The general flow to contact a service is to call it directly which causes a `not authorized` response. The result should include information about accepted pdps. Next the pdp is called, which will provide information which idps are accepted.The client then contacts the idp and does the authentication on behalf of the user. The resulting document, signed by the idp is passed to the pdp. The signed response from the pdp is then passed to the service again. The service ten contacts the pep with the document.

In the real world the points may not be single instances but merged. So a service may also include a pep, or an idp can be pdp too.

So have a look at your architecture/infrastructure.

Comment: is there some sort of a library that does this ? or do you have an implementation guide? because that is what I'm looking for

Comment: The authentication at the idp is idp specific. Please update your question and provide more information about the involved parties.

Comment: I'm not sure that I agree with you on the terminology you've chosen, Hannes. Most of the terms you used are more commonly found in access control systems (like SAML's cousin, XACML: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XACML). You do find PDP/PEP/etc., in the SAML glossary, but only in reference to Authorization, not Authentication (which is really where SAML plugs in).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language

Comment: @AndrewK. Valid point. If you look at the domain model (fig 1) of the SAML v1.0 spec, there is no reference to idp/pdp/pep but you see from the protocol flow authentication , attribution and authorization (as decision). So SAML does only define the protocol. But at the time idp/pdp/pep would realize the flow. Since Microsoft brached at 1.2, it's a mess out there ;)